# Drupal 7 list all the nodes that match a specific tag

Tags: taxonomy-terms

is it possible to pass a specific url to Drupal7 that lists all the nodes that has a specific tag? i'm searching for something similar to "?tag=" used by wordpress.

I've already created tags and added the tag field to my nodes

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are terms of a taxonomy vocabulary. Each term has its own page listing all the nodes for the term at `taxonomy/term/<tid>` where `<tid>` is the numaric term identifier. The [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module allow automatic creations of cleaner aliases for these pages using patterns like `<vocabulary-name>/<term-name>`. So instead of being at `taxonomy/term/42` the page for the "Foo Bar" tag will be at `tags/foo-bar`.